# How to pass a generic argument to a function pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, tree, function-pointers

I am trying to pass a function pointer to another function with an argument of type T.

Like so:

```
void preorder ( void ( *functptr ) (T&) ) // preorder traversal of tree
{
    preorder(root, functptr(T));

}
```

I understand that I need to pass an actual object to the function but this is being passed to another private function that actually knows what function it will be working with and I just need this public method to be a gateway between the two.

Comment: Whar shall be generic? Your code calls the function whose address you passed as argument to `preorder(funcptr)`. This function does not return a value (`void`). If you want _something_ passed to `preorder(root,funcptr)` you have to change the return value of funcptr: `void* (*funcptr)(T&))`.

Comment: Why did you tag this as C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
template <typename T>
void preorder ( void ( *functptr ) (T&) )
{
    preorder(root, functptr);
}
```